# MSB4018 The "GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest" task failed unexpectedly

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-mvc-2.1

I am trying to add localization to my web app(using Aspnetcore 2.1.1 and Razor pages). However, the moment I add more than one .resx file, it fails to compile with following error.

```
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest" task failed unexpectedly.
System.InvalidOperationException: An item with the name '' already exists.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.Task.Internal.Entry.AddChild(Entry child)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.Task.Manifest.AddElement(String originalPath, String assemblyResourceName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.Task.GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest.BuildManifest(EmbeddedItem[] processedItems)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.Task.GenerateEmbeddedResourcesManifest.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext() Service C:\Users\mishaukat\.nuget\packages\microsoft.extensions.fileproviders.embedded\2.1.1\build\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.targets   65
```

In my .csproj file, following property is set.

```
<GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>true</GenerateEmbeddedFilesManifest>
```

With the same setup, localization was working in AspNetCore 2.0.3.

Problem is the content of generated manifest file "Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded.Manifest.xml". The manifest file generator adds this line for one *.resx file.

```
<File Name=""><ResourcePath></ResourcePath></File>
```

When the generator finds another *.resx file, it tries to add the same line to the manifest xml, and fails saying "An item with the name '' already exists."

Answer (score 1):

it seems I am the second person who got this error :) 
According to [this link](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8121#issuecomment-410327701) I made some adjustments in the csproj file, adding `ExcludeFromManifest` flag to each resx file reference, which corrected my case.

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Resources/EntityListResources.resx">
  <ExcludeFromManifest>true</ExcludeFromManifest>
</EmbeddedResource>
```